# Retrieving Last Invoice Price in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this is simple for most of you!

I have an Invoices table like so:

```
+-----------+------------+------+-------+
| InvoiceID |    Date    | Item | Price |
+-----------+------------+------+-------+
|         1 | 15/04/2014 | A    |    12 |
|         2 | 20/04/2014 | A    |    20 |
|         3 | 20/04/2014 | A    |    27 |
|         4 | 20/04/2014 | B    |    29 |
|         5 | 28/04/2014 | C    |    16 |
|         6 | 28/04/2014 | B    |    11 |
+-----------+------------+------+-------+
```

I would like to retrieve the Price against the Last Invoice ID for each Item, so:

```
+------+-----------+
| Item | LastPrice |
+------+-----------+
| A    |    27     |
| B    |    11     |
| C    |    16     |
+------+-----------+
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I'm using SQL Server 2008

Many thanks in advance to any help received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by Item order by date desc) as r
   from dbo.YourTable
)
select * from cte where r = 1
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `order by invoiceid desc`

Comment: Probably *add* `invoiceid desc` as a tie-breaker. I don't particularly like the implicit statement that a higher invoice means later. What if the date on an invoice is later adjusted?

Comment: @AD.Net: That depends on what your definition of "latest" is. I saw a temporal value and went with that. Fortunately, it's trivial to change `[Date]` to `[InvoiceId]` if that is a better measure of which invoice came first.

Answer (score 0):

This may do your work :

```
SELECT Item,
       Price AS 'LastPrice'
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  InvoiceId IN (SELECT Max(InvoiceId)
                 FROM   MyTable
                 GROUP  BY Item)
```